# I have this template in django, but it's not working and if I start up index.html alone it works, why?

Tags: angularjs

html code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="nombreApp">
<head lang="en">
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title></title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.13/angular.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div ng-controller="controlador1">
nombre :{{ nombre }}
</div>

<script>
   var profileEditApp = angular.module('nombreApp', []);

   profileEditApp.config(['$httpProvider', '$interpolateProvider',
        function($httpProvider, $interpolateProvider) {
        /* for compatibility with django teplate engine */
        $interpolateProvider.startSymbol('{$');
        $interpolateProvider.endSymbol('$}');
        /* csrf */
        $httpProvider.defaults.xsrfHeaderName = 'X-CSRFToken';
        $httpProvider.defaults.xsrfCookieName = 'csrftoken';
    }]);

     profileEditApp = angular.module('nombreApp', []);
    profileEditApp.controller('controlador1',['$scope',function($scope){
        $scope.nombre = "Raulito"
    }])
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

It is not a problem of urls in django, that works me correctly
it is as if angularjs not work, someone has some solicion

Comment: @Mate I already made an edit to translate title and improve english grammar, however I'm not sure what he's trying to do.

Comment: I have this template  in django, but it's not working and if I start up index.html alone it works, why? Sorry

Answer (score -1):

The answer was that according to the settings had to put  {$nombre$} and so the data showed.

Comment: you had to put that *where*?